# Flutter Firestore permissions denied

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, rules

I have public permissions for my Flutter Android App.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But when I tries to query data like this:

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Firestore App"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("mydata").snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

          return FirestoreListview(documents: snapshot.data.documents);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirestoreListview extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents;

  FirestoreListview({this.documents});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: documents.length,
      itemExtent: 90.0,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){

        String name = documents[index].data["title"].toString();

            return Text(name);

      },
    );
  }
}
```

I Get this..

```
W/Firestore(12477): (0.6.6-dev) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(flutter_data) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/System.out(12477): com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I tried to recreate Flutter project and Firebase App but still getting same issue. With same settings I have a working Android native App project but for flutter its not working.
I have been trying since last 5 hours but I am unable to figure it out that what actual problem is?

Comment: Please put the query you trying to execute

Comment: Please check , I have updated my question..

Comment: Do you have a collection named myData?

Answer (score 8):

in my case, Its all because of Firebase Database rules configuration.
Changed below rules for my testing and its started working. (not recommended)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Before release set proper permission to access your database.

Comment: I updated the timestamp.date and it worked

```allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 4, 15);```